# Data binding inside <option> element in angular.js and jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, angularjs, cordova

I have recently added a multi-language support to my **jQuery-mobile/PhoneGap** app using [this great repo on gitHub](https://github.com/quammy/Multi-Language-support-with-Firebase-and-AngularJS).

It uses **[firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)** and **angular.js** to bind all the language dependant labels and texts in my app to the currently selected language, like in this example:

```
<h2>{{getWord("SELECTION_CRITERIA")}}</h2>
```

However, there are some language-dependant texts in my app that cannot be simply bound to language data, I have found this so far:

```
<select id="sel" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">{{getWord("SELECT_OFF")}}</option>
    <option value="on">{{getWord("SELECT_ON")}}</option>
</select>
```

The `<option>` element doesn't allow to bind it's text to the data (the rendered text is empty). I don't know why. I tried to test whether something like this could work:

```
<option value="off">{{1+2}}</option>
```

and yes, it displayed number 3 in the slider.

The angular.js part looks like this:

```
function LanguageCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.words = JSON.parse('{}');

    $scope.addWord = function(Name, Value) {
        $scope.words[Name] = Value;
    };

    $scope.getWord = function(Name) {
        return $scope.words[Name];
    };
}

var ref;
var refLang;
var onLangChange;

$(document).on("pageinit", "#mainPage", function(event) {
    ref = new Firebase('https://username.firebaseio.com/');
    ChangeLangTo("En"); //default lang
});

function ChangeLangTo(lang) {
    if (onLangChange !== undefined && onLangChange !== undefined) {
        refLang.off('child_changed', onLangChange);
    }

    refLang = ref.child(lang);

    //reading once all words
    refLang.once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
        var lang = dataSnapshot.val();
        angular.element($("#mainPage")).scope().$apply(function(scope) {
            $.each(lang, function(key, value) {
                scope.addWord(key, value);
            });
        });
    });

    //listening to changes
    onLangChange = refLang.on('child_changed', function(childSnapshot, prevChildName) {
        angular.element($("#mainPage")).scope().$apply(function(scope) {
            scope.addWord(childSnapshot.name(), childSnapshot.val());
        });
    });
```

The JSON from firebase that is parsed into that variable is very simple, like:

```
{
    "Cz": {
        "SELECT_ON":"Ano",
        "SELECT_OFF":"Ne"
    },

    "En": {
        "SELECT_ON":"On",
        "SELECT_OFF":"Off"
    }
}
```

I think that the `<button>` element won't work, too. And there are some cases of setting an element text via an attribute, like in this case:

```
<ul data-filter-placeholder="Search items..."></ul>
```

I would like to make this work, too:

```
<ul data-filter-placeholder="{{getWord("SEARCH_ITEMS")}}"></ul>
```

I am very new to angular.js, can someone please explain me how to make this work? I have read some documentation on HTML SELECT element with angular data-binding, but do not quite understand how to apply it.

Thanks!